# Why is jsoup so much faster than selenium or curl?

Tags: selenium, curl, jsoup

I have written numerous webscrapers over the past decade.  Initially in C++, then C#, but most recently, and extensively, in java and python.  These days, it is merely a coin toss as to whether I write a webscraper in java or python.  However, I have noticed for the past 3 or 4 years that somehow, some way, jsoup is significantly faster than either pycurl, pyrequest and certainly selenium.  What is jsoup's secret?  Why does it blow every other method out of the water with respect to speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about pycurl and pyrequest, but I can tell you about JSoup and Selenium. The big difference is that selenium webdriver drives a real browser with a live DOM, which before each action of selenium is performed needs to check if the element in question is still at the same state. This interaction with a real browser is naturally much more elaborated than what JSoup does: JSoup is a simple HTML parser. So it parses the HTML document (or XML) once and creates an in memory representation. Only JSoup commands will alter the DOM, so JSoup can be super efficient in dealing with this content.

The price that you pay with this approach is that JSoup naturally does not interpret or run Javascript. So websites that rely on asynchronous data loading will require you to understand it deeply and load the content directly as well. In selenium you can let the browser do all the work and "harvest" the rendered resulting HTML.

Comment: Thank you.  I was thinking some of the javascript content loaded in jsoup, but it may be that some PHP was delivering content that I could not otherwise scrape with simply curl, be it pycurl or batch scripted curls in Windows terminal or Linux bash.  My experience has been that JSoup can scrape some content that curling cannot and yet it scrapes this content FAR FAR faster than selenium (literally less than 1 second as compared to over 60 seconds when scraping on one recent app I did for COVID data).

Comment: Are you sure this is really about the time the content is parsed? Maybe you also measure the time the connection and retrieval of data takes. JSoup has of course methods for that, but this is not the strongest side of JSoup. Especially when you need to deal with cookies and SSL certificates you may want to look into Apache HttpClient.